# How can I grep through an array, while filtering out matches?

Tags: arrays, perl

Is there a quick and easy way to grep through an array finding the elements satisfying some test *and* remove these from the original array?

For example I would like

```
@a = (1, 7, 6, 3, 8, 4);
@b = grep_filter { $_ > 5 } @a;

# now @b = (7, 6, 8)
# and @a = (1, 3, 4)
```

In other words, I want to split an array into two arrays: those which match and those which do not match a certain condition.

Comment: why? It's trivial, and easy to read, to create 2 arrays from @a (`foreach (@a) { if( $_ > 5) { push @b, $_; } else { push  @c, $_; } }`) why do you need to do this "partially in place"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Know your libraries, mang.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(part);
part { $_>5 } (1, 7, 6, 3, 8, 4)
```

returns

```
(
    [1, 3, 4],
    [7, 6, 8],
)
```

Comment: Nice, pretty much what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

```
my @a = (1, 7, 6, 3, 8, 4);
my (@b, @c);    

push @{ $_ > 5 ? \@b : \@c }, $_ for @a;
```

Comment: +1 because it is a nice solution that doesn't require any external libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Using libraries is good, but for completeness, here is the function as specified in the question:

```
sub grep_filter (&\@) {
    my ($code, $src) = @_;
    my ($i, @ret) = 0;
    local *_;
    while ($i < @$src) {
        *_ = \$$src[$i];
        &$code
            ? push @ret, splice @$src, $i, 1
            : $i++
    }
    @ret
}

my @a = (1, 7, 6, 3, 8, 4);
my @b = grep_filter {$_ > 5} @a;

say "@a"; # 1 3 4
say "@b"; # 7 6 8
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```
@a = (1, 7, 6, 3, 8, 4);
@b = grep_filter { $_ > 5 } @a;
@a = grep_filter { $_ < 5 } @a;
```

do another grep with your condition negated.

Comment: `<` is not the strict negation of `>`.

Comment: @Alnitak - you are right, i didn't mentioned that, but I put `<` and not `<=` in order for the code to work as expected

Comment: @Tudor: why would a logic-error make code working as expected, instead of the correct <=?

Comment: @pavel looks to me like it only worked because 5 wasn't actually in the list.

Comment: If 5 was in the list (with an odd number of elements), how would it have been split in 2 same length lists?