# How do I filter filenames with regex instead of glob expressions?

Tags: arrays, perl, filtering

I am filtering files of a directory:

```
chdir '/home/brian/mypics/';
@picArray   = <*.JPG *.GIF *.jpg *.gif *.PNG *.png *.jpeg>;
@soundArray = <*.mid *.MID *.wav *.WAV *.mp3 *.MP3 *.wma *.WMA *.ogg *.OGG>;
```

I know there has to be a better and easier way, something that's case-insensitive and can allow for regex like `gif|png|jpe?g` and `wma|ogg|mp3|wave?|midi?`.

How can I have an array to catch all unknown file types (such if one was `.exe`, it would be in an array all of it's own as the other two never caught it)?

Comment: To answer the second part of the question, use [`part`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6706426#6706755) to partition a list. Next time better open a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

opendir/readdir would work:

```
opendir(my $dh, "/tmp/");
my @files = readdir($dh);
my @picArray = grep { /\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/i } @files;
my @soundArray = grep { /\.(wma|ogg|mp3|wave?|midi?)$/i } @files;
```

Comment: You'll probably want to adjust those regexes so they only match at the end of the filename (and probably look for the preceding dot also).  Otherwise, you'll wind up matching `gifford.txt`.

Comment: I just added `i` qualifiers to the regexps, since the OP asked for case-insensitive matching.